# Chrome doesn't support web kit speech?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webkit

My browser is upto date with Version 44.0.2403.155 m.

but [this](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/speech-input/index.html) link says `Your browser does not support web kit speech so a standard input box will be shown.` why is that? what did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

That link apparently uses some obsolete implementation.

Chrome platform status site [lists](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5908775487668224) a different example: http://simpl.info/stt/

Basic usage example by George Ornbo ([more](http://shapeshed.com/html5-speech-recognition-api/)):

```js
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognition.onresult = function(event) { 
  console.log(event) 
}
recognition.start();
```